# Estoy tratando de implementar volley para actualizar y eliminar registros por código pero tengo error

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Podrían ayudarme  a  implementar la libreria  volley  para eliminar  y actualizar  registros en android  por   código   y mysql.

```
 public void UpdateUser(final View view)
  {
    showLoadingDialog("Actualizando.............");

    // obtener  los valores  actuales de  los controles
    final  String Code=et1.getText().toString();
    final  String User=et2.getText().toString();
    final  String Pass=et3.getText().toString();
    final  String TipoUsuario=tipUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String newURL = Config.URL_UPDATE_USER;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();// Mapeo previo

    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_CODE, Code);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_USUARIO, User);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_PASS,Pass);
    map.put(Config.KEY_USER_TIPOUSER,TipoUsuario);

    // Crear nuevo objeto Json basado en el mapa
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(map);
    // Depurando objeto Json...
    Log.d(TAG, jobject.toString());

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    newURL,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                String estado = response.getString("estado");

                                if(estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                    //Actualización  exitosa.
                                    //Procedemos a hacer las operaciones pertinentes
                                    hideLoadingDialog();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se actualizó el  Usuario  con éxito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    // No  existe  registro con ese  código  para  actualizar
                                    hideLoadingDialog();

                                    Snackbar.make(view, "No se actualizó  por que no existe un registro con este  código", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vd))
                                            .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                }
                                            }).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                            hideLoadingDialog();

                            Snackbar.make(view, "Por algún  otro motivo no se  pudo actualizar : " + error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vd))
                                    .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                        }
                                    }).show();
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Este  en  mi código JAVA android.

**Este es  mi código PHP**

```
   <?php 
   require('conexion.php');

   $Code=$_GET['Code'];

   $consulta="SELECT * from tb_usuario WHERE Code=?";
   $comando=$conn->prepare($consulta);
   $comando->execute(array($Code));
   $row=$comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   if($row)
{
    $Code=$_GET['Code'];
    $User=$_GET['User'];
    $Pass=$_GET['Pass'];
    $TipoUsuario=$_GET['TipoUsuario'];

    // Creando consulta UPDATE
      $consulta = "UPDATE tb_usuario" .
        " SET User=?, Pass=?,TipoUsuario=? " .
        "WHERE Code=?";

    // Preparar la sentencia
    $cmd = $conn->prepare($consulta);

    // Relacionar y ejecutar la sentencia
    $cmd->execute(array($User,$Pass,$TipoUsuario,$Code));
    // Código de éxito
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Actualización exitosa')
    );
   }
   else
{
   // Código de  error
      print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'No se actualizó  por que  no hay un Usuario  con este  código')
    );
```

}

?>

Comment: ¿Dónde están los datos que quieres eliminar, en una BD en un servidor remoto? ¿Qué error te está dando? Tu método `deleteJSON` no hace ninguna acción de borrado...

Comment: De inicio no entiendo por qué si esperas un JSON utilizas StringRequest y no un JsonObjectRequest, y no podemos ayudarte si no aclaras que error te está dando el código, si es en tu app o en tu PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explico un poco por encima como lo hago yo, algo similar a lo que tu quieres hacer.

Yo tengo una serie de archivos en PHP a los cuales me conecto para crear, eliminar, modificar una serie de datos. Por ejemplo eliminar datos, como en tu caso. Este es el archivo PHP al que yo hago la peticion:

```
<?php
/**
 * Elimina una reserva de la base de datos
 * identificada por su id
 */

require 'Reserva.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Decodificando formato Json
    $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    $retorno = Reserva::delete($body['idReserva']);

    if ($retorno) {
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '1',
                'mensaje' => 'Eliminacion exitosa')
        );
    } else {
        print json_encode(
            array(
                'estado' => '2',
                'mensaje' => 'Eliminacion fallida')
        );
    }
}
```

Y esta es la parte que ejecuta la sentencia mysql para eliminar el dato:

```
<?php

/**
 * Representa el la estructura de las reservas
 * almacenadas en la base de datos
 */
require 'Database.php';

class Reserva
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }

...


/**
     * Eliminar el registro con el identificador especificado
     *
     * @param $idReserva identificador de la reserva
     * @return bool Respuesta de la eliminación
     */
    public static function delete($idReserva)
    {
        // Sentencia DELETE
        $comando = "DELETE FROM reservas WHERE idReserva=?";

        // Preparar la sentencia
        $sentencia = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($comando);

        return $sentencia->execute(array($idReserva));
    }
}

?>
```

Bueno, hasta aquí lo que sería la parte del servidor. En cuanto al cliente, Android en este caso, lo que yo hago es llamar a este servicio con la libreria Volley y hacer lo pertinente con la respuesta obtenida. Este es el codigo:

```
public void crearCuenta(final View view) {

        showLoadingDialog("Eliminando...");

        // Obtener valores actuales de los controles
        String id = ... //el id del elemento a eliminar

        String newURL = Constantes.DELETE + "?idReserva=" + id;

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(
                new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        newURL,
                        null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                try {
                                    String estado = response.getString("estado");

                                    if(estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                                        //Eliminacion exitosa.
                                        //Procedemos a hacer las operaciones pertinentes
                                        hideLoadingDialog();

                                        Snackbar.make(view, "Exito en la eliminacion", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                                .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
                                                .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                                    }
                                                }).show();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        hideLoadingDialog();

                                        Snackbar.make(view, "Error eliminando", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                                .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
                                                .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                                    }
                                                }).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.getMessage());
                                hideLoadingDialog();

                                Snackbar.make(view, "Error de comunicacion eliminando: " + error.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
                                        .setAction("Aceptar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                            }
                                        }).show();
                            }
                        }

                ) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                        return headers;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8" + getParamsEncoding();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado o al menos haberte dado una pequeña pista o idea.

Para cualquier otra duda, no dudes en preguntar.

Saludos.

--------------------EDIT----------------------
Añado los archivos que uso para conectarme a la base de datos:

```
<?php
/**
 * Provee las constantes para conectarse a la base de datos
 * Mysql.
 */
define("HOSTNAME", "xxxxxxxxxxx");// Nombre del host
define("DATABASE", "xxxxxxxxxxx"); // Nombre de la base de datos
define("USERNAME", "xxxxxxxxxxx"); // Nombre del usuario
define("PASSWORD", "xxxxxxxxxxx"); // Nombre de la constrase�a
?>

<?php
/**
 * Clase que envuelve una instancia de la clase PDO
 * para el manejo de la base de datos
 */

require_once 'mysql_login.php';


    class Database
    {

        /**
         * Única instancia de la clase
         */
        private static $db = null;

        /**
         * Instancia de PDO
         */
        private static $pdo;

        final private function __construct()
        {
            try {
                // Crear nueva conexión PDO
                self::getDb();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                // Manejo de excepciones
            }


        }

        /**
         * Retorna en la única instancia de la clase
         * @return Database|null
         */
        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (self::$db === null) {
                self::$db = new self();
            }
            return self::$db;
        }

        /**
         * Crear una nueva conexión PDO basada
         * en los datos de conexión
         * @return PDO Objeto PDO
         */
        public function getDb()
        {
            if (self::$pdo == null) {
                self::$pdo = new PDO(
                    'mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE .
                    ';host=' . HOSTNAME .
                    ';port:3306;'. // Eliminar este elemento si se usa una instalación por defecto
                    ';charset=utf8',
                    USERNAME,
                    PASSWORD,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
                );

                // Habilitar excepciones
                self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }

            return self::$pdo;
        }

        /**
         * Evita la clonación del objeto
         */
        final protected function __clone()
        {
        }

        function _destructor()
        {
            self::$pdo = null;
        }
    }

?>
```

--------------------Nuevo Edit-------------------

Añado los metodos para mostrar u ocultar los loadingdialog:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
        try {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            }
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMessage(texto);
            progressDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            progressDialog = null;
        }

    }

    public void hideLoadingDialog() {
        try {
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception a) {
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He editado el final de mi respuesta. Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Te he añadido como creo yo los loadingDialog. Los tengo definidos en una clase base que luego uso en casa nueva activity extendiendo de esta clase base.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. No te marca error porque supongo que no es un error de la app sino del codigo PHP y en eso yo ya poco te puedo ayudar, es mas, seria mas un error de esa sección y no de Android. Reconozco mis limitaciones en PHP, se lo justito y la verdad es que no te puedo ayudar en eso.